# MySql Query for WordPress Recent Posts Need to Link to Individual Posts

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

This code displays the most recent 3 posts in WordPress. However, when following the links, every link connects to the most recent post, not the post associated with the excerpt. I need the excerpt links to connect to their associated full posts.

I did not code this and I realize it's deprecated. I've also tried WP recent posts function and shortcodes which don't work. The PHP code is so messed up that it causes lots of issues. I have very limited knowledge of MySql.

```
              $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * from wp_term_relationships where term_taxonomy_id = '3' ORDER BY object_id DESC LIMIT 3 ");
              while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
              {
                  $object_id = $row['object_id'];
            $sql_posts = mysql_query("SELECT * From wp_posts  where ID = '$object_id' AND post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 3");
            while($row_posts = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_posts))
                {?>
                <div class=" gaming_news_col col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                    <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php echo $row_posts['post_title'];?></h4>
                    <p><?php 
                        $content = $row_posts['post_content'];
                        $post_content = myTruncate($content, 150, " ");
                        echo $post_content;
                        ?></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The method myTruncate cuts the text to some specific range, for instance, at your case, it will show only first 150 characters. If you want to show the full text, do not use myTruncate at all. Just echo the content.

```
$content = $row_posts['post_content'];
echo $post_content;
```

This should do the trick and not cut the text to specified limit.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that's not what I'm trying to do. I want to truncate to 150 characters for the excerpts. I need to be able to attach a permalink to each excerpt that will open another window and display the entire post. Currently the permalink only opens the latest post. I want all 3 truncated excerpts to open links to pages with the associated full posts. Does that make sense?

Comment: use echo get_permalink(); in order to get the link associated with the specific ID. Put it in whatever html tag you want, within the content. I hope this helps. @TaraBriscoe

Comment: When I add echo get_permalink(); it shows the link, but it's still the same link for the most recent post after all 3 excerpts. I had it linking before with a button, but it has the same problem. Do I have to repeat the entire sql query sequence for each separate term_taxonomy_id in order to get the right permalink for each excerpt? There must be an easier way.